# Reshape row wise w/ different starting/ending elements number

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

The problem is:

```
Product of known dimensions, 3, not divisible into total number of elements, 16.
```

this because i want to `reshape` a `16x1` matrix in a `3x6` matrix. The problem is that the start matrix has 16 elements and the final matrix has 18. Is there a smart way to reshape row wise and filling the missing element with 0s till the number of elements matches?

Of course I need a general method independent from those number since the size of matrices can change.

TBN: 0s should be at the end of the matrix

Comment: Where do you want those missing elements replaced by 0's to be? All at the end?

Comment: As Benoit said, the location of those missing elements needs to be known before reshaping.  Without it, it would be impossible to do what you ask.

Comment: Yup, sorry guys! The 0 elements goes to the end :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Approach #1

You can use **[`vec2mat`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html)** that's part of the **Communications System Toolbox**, assuming `A` as the input vector -

```
ncols = 6; %// number of columns needed in the output
out = vec2mat(A,ncols)
```

Sample run -

```
>> A'
ans =
     4     9     8     9     6     1     8     9     7     7     7     4     6     2     7     1
>> out
out =
     4     9     8     9     6     1
     8     9     7     7     7     4
     6     2     7     1     0     0
```

---

### Approach #2

If you don't have that toolbox, you can work with the basic functions to achieve the same -

```
out = zeros([ncols ceil(numel(A)/ncols)]);
out(1:numel(A)) = A;
out = out.'
```

Comment: May I ask a question? Is this approach possibile if `ncols` is a vector? Let's say that i need to take the first 6 elements for the first row of `out`, then another 4 elements of `A`and then 2 0's to complete the row, ecc

Comment: @gmeroni I think that would be a lot different from what's proposed in the question posted, so it would suit better as a new question. Also, please consider using a sample matrix to demonstrate the expected output. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can also pre-allocate a vector of zeroes, fill in your data for as many elements as there are in your vector, then reshape it when you're done:

```
vec = 1:16; %// Example data
numRows = 6;
numCols = 3;
newVec = zeros(1:numRows*numCols);
newVec(1:numel(vec)) = vec;
newMat = reshape(newVec, numRows, numCols);
```

Comment: @LuisMendo - Graçias :)

Comment: ¡De nada! Oh and it's "gracias". Unlike French, Spanish doesn't have the "ç" letter ;-)

Comment: @LuisMendo - oops! I was under the impression that there was.  My apologies!

Comment: No problem at all! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should add zeros in the beginnig. What I mean:

```
vec      = [1:16]'
nRow     = 3;
nCol     = 6;
zeroFill = nRow * nCol - length(vec);
newVec   = [vec; zeros(zeroFill, 1)];
mat      = reshape(newVec, [nRow nCol])
```