# vec2mat w/ different number of columns

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

Referring to [Reshape row wise w/ different starting/ending elements number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27486493/reshape-row-wise-w-different-starting-ending-elements-number) @Divakar came with a nice solution but, **what if the number of columns is not always the same?**

*Sample run -*

```
>> A'
ans =
     4     9     8     9     6     1     8     9     7     7     7     4     6     2     7     1
>> out
out =
     4     9     8     9     0     0
     6     1     8     9     7     7
     7     4     6     2     7     1
```

I took only the first 4 terms of A and put them in out, then fill the rest 2 empty cell with 0's. So the `ncols = [4 6 6]`. Unfortunately `vet2mat` doesn't allow vector as columns number.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So, `sum(ncols)` has to be equal to `numel(A)`? `ncols` thus given would always satisfy that condition?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27946552/2338750).

Comment: @Divakar the expected output is `out`. If you look it closely is different from you question since there are 2 0's in the first row instead of the last one :).  Yes, `numel(A) = sum(ncols)`

Comment: @StewieGriffin Hey, I _knew_ I had used `accumarray` this way before somewhere! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can employ [**`bsxfun`**](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)'s masking capability here -

```
%// Random inputs
A = randi(9,1,15)
ncols = [4 6 5]

%// Initialize output arary of transposed size as compared to the desired 
%// output arary size, as we need to insert values into it row-wise and MATLAB 
%// follows column-major indexing
out = zeros(max(ncols),numel(ncols)); 

mask =  bsxfun(@le,[1:max(ncols)]',ncols); %//'# valid positions mask for output
out(mask) = A; %// insert input array elements
out = out.' %//'# transpose output back to the desired output array size
```

Code run -

```
A =
     5     3     7     2     7     2     4     6     8     1     9     7     5     4     5
ncols =
     4     6     5
out =
     5     3     7     2     0     0
     7     2     4     6     8     1
     9     7     5     4     5     0
```

Comment: why use `double`? It seems like a waste.

Comment: @Memming Because `bsxfun` creates a logical array and as such you cant input/replace values from A into it. Alternative would be to create another array of zeros and then use the mask obtained from `bsxfun` for logical indexing.

Comment: Thanks @Divakar but in this example you are taking row-wise and not column-wise. The first row should be `2 4 9 8 0 0 `

Comment: Way to go! I was only left with the `accumarray` option :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) for that:

```
A = [4 9 8 9 6 1 8 9 7 7 7 4 6 2 7 1].'; %'// data
ncols = [4 6 6]; %// columns
n = max(ncols);
cs = cumsum(ncols);
ind = 1;
ind(cs+1) = 1;
ind = cumsum(ind(1:end-1)); %// `ind` tells the row for each element of A
result = accumarray(ind(:), A(:), [], @(x) {[x; zeros(n-numel(x),1)]}); %// split `A` as 
    %// dictated by `ind`, and fill with zeros. Each group is put into a cell.
result = [result{:}].'; %'// concatenate all cells
```

Comment: Yup! This should work too! :) Good alternative for OP to work with.